# VS2022 .Net 6 winform app - Designer not loading

Tags: winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a new Winform app targetted at .Net 6 using VS2022. When creating the project or re-opening a project, I always get stuck with the Loading Designer ....  message on the screen.

I have researched this and seen numerous things to try, but none have worked. The only clue I have seen is on then Output: Windows Forms which says:

> [10:56:14.205597] warn: DPI mode SystemAware specified for the project
> is different from the DPI mode specified for the designer. Winforms
> designer will have DPI mode DpiUnaware  [10:56:15.512211] fail:
> [Test10]: Failed to launch design tools server process process
> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set process DPI mode value to: DpiUnaware.
> at Microsoft.WinForms.Utilities.Desktop.DpiHelper.SetDesignerProcessDpiAwareness(DpiAwarenessContext
> dpiContext)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>
> For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at
> https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.

I do not get the banner at the top regarding DPI.

I can create a Framework app no problem, but I know .Net has a different designer.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2022 with no change.

I tried running VS2022 as admin.  Tried setting scaling to 100% (unraddable), but still fails. Tried selecting .net 7, same result.

Maybe there is some extension or package I need.

Comment: *Failed to launch design tools server process*, that's fatal to the designer.  You need to get this machine stable again, perhaps start by disabling anti-malware.

Comment: Disabled Norton AV, still the same.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The only difference is that the Designer works when I start Visual Studio as Admin. But as a normal user it hangs...
Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. We need first to get more information about what is happening, to do that, in VS go to `Tools->Options->Windows Forms Designer` and set the logging level to `Verbose` as you see in the below image:

[image: Changing option to versbose]

2. Clean your solution or project, then rebuild and restart visual studio.
3. Double-click on your form file to open your form designer, the to the console window and select `Windows Form` as shown below:

[image: Windows Forms Designer]

4. Now you will see more logs and that should help you know what is happening internally. For me the problem was saying clearly that the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions v6.0.0` was missing as shown in the error message here:

```
[00:13:10.797915] fail: [Project]: Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
[00:13:10.797915] fail: [Project]: File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
[00:13:10.797915] fail: [Project]:    at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.Program.Main(String[] args, IEnumerable`1 designTimeAssemblies, Action fixUpNetTypes)
[00:13:10.797915] fail: [Project]:    at DesignToolsServerX64.Program.Main(String[] args)
[00:15:09.118001] fail: [Project]: Timed out while connecting to named pipe: DesignToolsServer.8229ad3e-0143-45e1-9804-41c09eeea847
```

If your problem was similar to mine try these steps in order:

1. Add your missing package using your project Nuget package manager and select the same version shown in the Windows Forms error message, rebuild your project then restart VS. For me it was 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0' (this fixed the problem for me)
2. If this didn't work, close VS and go to [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) and download the missing package version manually, then open it using `7zip` or `Winrar` and navigate to `/lib/net*.*` (for me it was net6.0, which is my project framework version of Net), then extract that dll to some folder, open `cmd` as administrator and extract the following command: `gacutil /i [path to your dll]`. Now restart VS and see if it worked for you. Note: `gacutil` is located in different paths on different Windows versions, for my Win11 it was at the following location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil.exe`

If all above didn't work, you can still try the following solutions:

- Change the platform target: Try changing the platform target from 64 to 32 or to `AnyCPU` then rebuild your project and restart VS after each change.
- Set your `Target OS` to `Windows` and select a `10.*` `Target OS Version` then also rebuild and restart VS, see example image below:
  [image: selecting Target OS]
- The final shot is to create a new project and move your source code files to it. (this is not recommended because it will 100% works in almost all cases, but you will face the same issue again when you restart VS)